# Preview image before uploading using input type image

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

If I'm using `img` tag and after clicking simple button - image preview working:

**HTML**

```
<form runat="server">
  <input type='file' id="imgInp" />
  <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" /> <--- in this place img
</form>
```

**JS**

```
function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
    }
    
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]); // convert to base64 string
  }
}

$("#imgInp").change(function() {
  readURL(this);
});
```

But when I'm trying to hide button and make image clickable (to achieve it using `input type="image"`) preview not working, after choosing image no effect, not changing default image).

Default clickable image is like "Click here to upload photo".

**HTML**

```
<form runat="server">               
    <div class="thumb-preview">
        <input type="image" id="blah" src="<?=path?>/images/upload.png"/> <-- input type image
        <input type='file' id="imgInp" style="display: none;" />
    </div>                            
</form>
```

**JS**

```
function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
    }
    
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]); // convert to base64 string
  }
}

$("#imgInp").change(function() {
  readURL(this);
});

$("input[type='image']").click(function() {
    $("input[id='imgInp']").click();
});
```

Have you ideas how to change the image of `input type="image"`?

Comment: What is the issue you are having  ? Any console.log errors. Can you be specific on the issues you have currently ?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping "But when I'm trying to hide button and make image clickable (to achieve it using input type="image") preview not working, after choosing image no effect, not changing default image)". By F12 > Console, there are no any errors. Simple src path of `<input type="image"` not overwriting

Comment: @AlwaysHelping Yes, exactly! Thank you, what I missed was `e.preventDefault()`... Post it as answer, I will accept.

Comment: Thank you so much. Posted an answer. I will add some explanation as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [e.PreventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) method in your click function to to make sure your `click` `type=image` is not `reloading` the page every time you click on it.!

**Live Demo:**

```js
function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]); // convert to base64 string
  }
}

$("#imgInp").change(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  readURL(this);
});

$("input[type='image']").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $("input[id='imgInp']").click();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form runat="server">               
    <div class="thumb-preview">
        <input type="image" id="blah" src="https://img.icons8.com/dotty/80/000000/upload.png"/> 
        <input type='file' id="imgInp" style="display: none;" />
    </div>                            
</form>
```